# Play a sound at a certain point in another sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio

```
 var audioElm3 = document.getElementById('player');
        if (audioElm3.currentTime === "115") {
            document.getElementById('coverBirds').play();
            console.log("firing");
        };
```

So the intention is to play the sound "coverBirds" at a certain point during the running of the 'player' sound. The problem is, nothing happens when I load the page, and nothing shows up on the console either, strangely. These are both HTML5 audio elements. I hope that explains it enough?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook your javascript up to your `document.getElementById('player')`'s timeupdate event

```
document.getElementById('player').ontimeupdate = function(){
//CODE GOES HERE
}
```

This event fires whenever the time indicated by currentTime changes, allowing you to compare to the 115 seconds you need and then fire off the coverBirds audio element. Note `currentTime` will almost never return a nice round number and example of logging the output of currentTime to the console is

> LOG: 0
>   LOG: 0.23746030032634735
>   LOG: 0.4874148964881897
>   LOG: 0.7374603152275085
>   LOG: 0.9872788786888123
>   LOG: 1.2373242378234863
>   LOG: 1.4874602556228637

You will need to adjust the logic in your if statment accordingly, to either round the value you receive form currentTime or provide a range with which to begin play inside of.

[timeupdate event @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/timeupdate)

Comment: Thankyou, if possible can you help me with the syntax? I'm new to coding and wouldn't really know how to 'hook my javascript up to x'

Comment: document.getElementById('player').ontimeupdate = function(){
    var audioElm3 = document.getElementById('player');
    if (audioElm3.currentTime === "2") {
        document.getElementById('coverBirds').play();
        console.log("firing");
    }
    };


so this is my code so far, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: currentTime will almost never return a nice round number like "2" if you adjust your code to print out the currentTime to console `console.log(audioElm3.currentTime)` youll see whats actually returned and then you decided what to do from there to adjust your logic. Updated the answer to include the information about currentTime